# Regex expression: filter files since 1970? Year number encoded in the file name string

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of files for each months and year stretching from 1881-2021. Names are in format month/year and look like:

- `01_Jan/193501asc.gz`
- `09_Sep/188209asc.gz`
- `01_Jan/197501asc.gz`
- `07_Jul/202107asc.gz`

I wonder how to write a regex expression to filter only the files that more then 1970? (period 1970-2021?)
I have tried:

```
file_ls <- list.files(paste(myPath, "data", sep = "/"), 
                          pattern = "[>1970]",
                          #pattern = "[1970-2021]",
                          #pattern="*\\.gz$", # ending character
                          recursive=TRUE)
```

Expected files to return (years in period 1970-2021):

- `01_Jan/197501asc.gz`
- `07_Jul/202107asc.gz`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a regex is the best way to go here. If you want to do some numerical filtering, I would just process the `file_ls` after you list all the `*.gz`. For example you could use:

```r
s <- c("193501asc.gz", "188209asc.gz", "197501asc.gz", "202107asc.gz")

f <- function(x, y = 1970) {
  first4 <- substr(x, 1, 4)
  year <- as.numeric(first4)
  year >= y
}

s[f(s)]
#> [1] "197501asc.gz" "202107asc.gz"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @DanAdams, I have changed my question and now  wish to filter the years from 1970-2021. So the simple using '^20' (filtering only years >2000) does not work anymore. Maybe y have another suggestion how to adapt regex?  Thank you!

Comment: could just change to `pattern = "^2"` right?

Comment: to filter the years since 1970? no, this does not work unfortunately...

Comment: I misread. Ok let me see..

Comment: that's look great! I like the little function convertng the year back to numeric value. One last question: how to please operate **within** the individual folders? eg. if the `s <- c("jan_01/193501asc.gz", "feb_02/188209asc.gz", "mar_03/197501asc.gz", "apr_04/202107asc.gz")`? Just using `first4 <- substr(x, 8, 11)` ? maybe something more versatile? Thank you again!

Comment: That would probably work. If you can post a new question where you fully explain the situation with some example filenames, you will probably get a better answer.